# keeping same div pixel size in different browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have this drop-up menu

```css
.taskbar-start-dropup {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 36px;
 left: 3px;
 box-shadow: -1px -1px 0px 0px #000 inset, -2px -2px 0px 0px #868A8E inset,
          1px 1px 0px 0px #C2C5CA inset, 2px 2px 0px 0px #FFF inset;
 background-color: #C2C5CA;
 width: 300px;
 height: 453px;
 
}
.taskbar-start-dropup-item {
 color: black;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 215px;
 top: 2px;
 left: 42px;
 right: 2px;
 bottom: 2px;
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 font-size: 12px;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 cursor: default;
}
.taskbar-start-dropup-item:hover {
 background-color: blue;
}
.show {
 display: block;
}
#taskbar-start-dropup-logo {
 height: 448px;
 width: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 left: 2px;
 background-color: blue;
}
.taskbar-start-dropup-divider {
 height: 2px;
 width: 240px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px 0px #FFF inset, 1px 1px 0px 0px #868A8E inset;
}
```

```html
 <div id="taskbar-start-dropup" class="show taskbar-start-dropup">
  <div id="taskbar-start-dropup-logo"></div> <!-- TODO: change to img -->
  <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 1</div>
  <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 2</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 3</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 4</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 5</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 6</div>
  <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-divider"></div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item" id="logout">PLACEHOLDER log out</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item" id="shutdown">PLACEHOLDER shutdown</div>
   </div>
```

I defined all the sizes by pixel, because I'm still very new to CSS/Html and don't know if the alternatives are that exact? However if I open it in Firefox now the dropup menu seems fine

[image: firefox screenshot]

but once I open it in Chrome

[image: chrome screenshot]

the size of the dropup menu doesn't seem to fit with the dropup items 
anymore. Is there any way for me to avoid this? Fix this? Better alternatives?

I'm not sure if a jsfiddle would be necessary in this case (and I'm a tad uncomfortable to do so if it isn't), but I have one at hand if it'd be helpful, just comment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good and universal solution, but I entirely dropped out the height attribute now in .taskbar-start-dropup and instead gave it a padding of 5px

I also gave the .taskbar-start-dropup-logo a height of 98%

I tried on Chrome and Firefox just now and it seems to work fine, gonna try it at home later and maybe on another browser, hopefully this'll work

**Edit:** worked at home on Chrome, Firefox and Edge too

Here's the code:

```css
.taskbar-start-dropup {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 36px;
 left: 3px;
 box-shadow: -1px -1px 0px 0px #000 inset, -2px -2px 0px 0px #868A8E inset,
          1px 1px 0px 0px #C2C5CA inset, 2px 2px 0px 0px #FFF inset;
 background-color: #C2C5CA;
 width: 300px;
 padding-bottom: 5px; /* removed height & added padding-bottom */
}
.taskbar-start-dropup-item {
 color: black;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 215px;
 top: 2px;
 left: 42px;
 right: 2px;
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 font-size: 12px;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 cursor: default;
}
.taskbar-start-dropup-item a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
.taskbar-start-dropup-item:hover {
 background-color: blue;
}
.show {
 display: block;
}
#taskbar-start-dropup-logo {
 height: 98.8%; /* set height to THIS mess */
 width: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 left: 2px;
 background-color: blue;
}
.taskbar-start-dropup-divider {
 height: 2px;
 width: 240px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px 0px #FFF inset, 1px 1px 0px 0px #868A8E inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="taskbar-start-dropup" class="taskbar-start-dropup show">
  <div id="taskbar-start-dropup-logo"></div> <!-- TODO: change to img -->
  <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 1</div>
  <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 2</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 3</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 4</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 5</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item">link 6</div>
  <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-divider"></div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item" id="logout">PLACEHOLDER log out</div>
   <div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item" id="shutdown"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxVVd5fZNeo">PLACEHOLDER shutdown</a></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You answer is in the css implementation taskbar-start-dropup-item.

```
.taskbar-start-dropup-item {
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 215px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 42px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;  <-- this line specifies 2px padding take it off
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Alternatively:

You can specify inner html styling of this form:

```
<div class="taskbar-start-dropup-item" id="shutdown" style="bottom: 0px;">PLACEHOLDER shutdown</div>
      </div>
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't seem to do a difference at all, unfortunately :(

Comment: Well ur code snippet works fine on me browser. try inspecting the element and fiddling with it around you can insepct an element by right clicking on it and inspect :)

Comment: huh okay, thats really weird :/ i just tried the snipped and THAT works too for me, it doesn't in my full code, though, at least not once I switch to Chrome

Comment: That mean there is some styling issue in your code. Reason being you have more css styling somewhere in your header file.

Comment: probably, i just edited the original question and added a jsfiddle of my whole code :0

Comment: Change your pading from 20 to 20.5. Or just replace the css witht he one i posted below:                                                                               
       .taskbar-start-dropup-item {
 color: black;
 padding: 20.5px;
 width: 215px;
 top: 2px;
 left: 42px;
 right: 2px;
 bottom: 2px;
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 font-size: 12px;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 cursor: default;
}

Comment: padding: 20.5px makes it look like this http://puu.sh/wUFjJ/9fec2d4f67.png